# Is there any way that I can speed up the adding of new elements to a page when using the C# back end?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have code that works but I notice it's rather slow to create the page elements.

Here's what I have so far. Note that I'm not adding everything at once as I found that when I did the page creation was even slower.

```
    public void CreateSwitchSection(bool? selected)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("FrameBorder", out object frameBorder);
        var st = new StackLayout { Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical, Spacing = 0 };
        st.Children.Add(AddSwitchRows(selected, App.cardSetWithWordCount.Take(20)));
        st.Children.Add(AddSwitchRows(selected, App.cardSetWithWordCount.Skip(20).Take(20)));
        st.Children.Add(AddSwitchRows(selected, App.cardSetWithWordCount.Skip(40).Take(20)));
        st.Children.Add(AddSwitchRows(selected, App.cardSetWithWordCount.Skip(60).Take(20)));
        st.Children.Add(AddSwitchRows(selected, App.cardSetWithWordCount.Skip(80).Take(20)));
        var fr = new Frame { Style = (Style)frameBorder };
        var fs = new FrameStack { };
        var ht = new HeaderTemplate()
        {
            Text = "CHOOSE CARD SETS FOR THE DECK"
        };
        fs.Children.Add(ht);
        fs.Children.Add(st);
        fs.Children.Add(new LineTemplate());
        fr.Content = fs;
        details.Children.Clear();
        details.Children.Add(fr);
    }

    private StackLayout AddSwitchRows(bool? selected, IEnumerable<CardSetWithWordCount> data)
    {
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Spacing = 0
        };

        foreach (var x in data)
        {
            var cell = new BadgeGridTemplate
            {
                BindingContext = x,
                Text = x.Name,
                State = selected == true ? "E" : "D",
                Message = x.TotalWordCount.ToString(),
                TapCommand = (Command)vm.SelectCardSetCmd,
                RowId = x.Id,
                Separator = true
            };
            stack.Children.Add(cell);
        }
        return stack;
    }
```

For reference here is the BadgeGridTemplate I coded:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<t:BaseGridTemplate xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:t="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
                    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Behaviors;assembly=Behaviors" 
                    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Japanese.Converters;assembly=Japanese" 
                    x:Class="Japanese.Templates.BadgeGridTemplate" 
                    x:Name="this" 
                    HeightRequest="{DynamicResource GridHeight}" Margin="0"
    Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding Separator, Source={x:Reference this}}" BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource LineColor}" Margin="0" />
    <Grid Padding="20,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Text,  Source={x:Reference this}}" TextColor="{DynamicResource LabelColor}" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" WidthRequest="30" />
        <t:Button Grid.Column="1" Meta="GsT" RowId="{Binding RowId, Source={x:Reference this}}" State="{Binding State, Source={x:Reference this}}" TapCommand="{Binding TapCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" Text="{Binding Message, Source={x:Reference this}}" Theme="{Binding Theme}" WidthRequest="30" />
    </Grid>
</t:BaseGridTemplate>
```

Comment: Seems to be quite optimized to me!

Comment: Do you have the code for App.cardSetWithWordCount ? Is it just a variable ?

Comment: @G.hakim - the problem is that it seems to take 1-2 seconds to display and when I timed the database operations it was just milliseconds.  So I am wondering if there is any way I can speed up the creation of those elements.

Comment: Instead of trying to create multiple nested layouts - try to use one single layout like grid or flex layout to achieve same look and feel. The higher the number of layouts, the longer it will take to render.

Comment: The problem is that this code sample in question tries to render all the 100 elements on screen at once.even  if the user is looking at only a few of them at a time. That's why you are looking at the delay of 1-3 seconds.

Comment: Did u ever find a solutions having same issue but im just adding six dynamic buttons

Answer (score 4):

### What are we trying to do:

Take a list of data from some source, Put them in a list

### What your code is doing:

taking all the data building(all 100 AddSwitchRows ) UI right then.
Those hundreds of UI has to be rendered all at once on the screen. (even if the user is not going to look at them all)

### Suggestion: How should we do this:

I highly suggest using a Listview. 
Or [FlowListview for grids https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls)

### Why?

Listview will only try to draw UI for the screen user is looking at.

If there are a thousand more items needed. It will be built only when the user scrolls down to that portion.

If you want to make multiple kinds of cells which depends on the data you receive we should use DataTemplate with ListView

[More Information on Microsoft's Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

**Example**
I have added 1000 items in the listView's **ItemSource** when clicked on the button in header.
You can add your template in the **Listview.datatemplate** tag and bind your ViewModel to this view
**View**
And if you want to change item's view as per a property value. Use [DataTemplate selecter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector) property of ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:stackAnswerApp"
             x:Class="stackAnswerApp.MainPage"
             x:Name="Root">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}" RowHeight="100">
        <ListView.Header>
            <Button Text="Start Adding" Command="{Binding StartAddingItems}" />
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <!-- whatever is your template -->
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text1}" />
                        <Button BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                Text="Go" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root},Path=BindingContext}"
                                Command="{Binding  ButtonTapped}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel**

```
class AModel
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
    }

    class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AModel> ListItems { get; set; }
        private const int TotalRows = 1000;

        public ICommand StartAddingItems
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    //add too many items in the list
                    await Task.Run(async () => { await AddItemsToList(); });
                });
            }
        }

        private async Task AddItemsToList()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < TotalRows; i++)
            {
                ListItems.Add(new AModel() {Text1 = $"index {i}", Text2 = $"tap {i}"});
            }
        }

        public ICommand ButtonTapped
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command((() =>
                {
                    //button in the list was tapped
                }));
            }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            ListItems = new ObservableCollection<AModel>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please tell me if you want an even more detailed example. I may learn something new along.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using BatchBegin() on stacks variable before the loop of child adds in your function AddSwitchRows and BatchCommit() after the loop. And if that works, do the same to your parent stack variable st in CreateSwitchSection.

Ie.
stacks.BatchBegin();
foreach var x in data
{
…
}
stacks.BatchCommit();

This may resolve it as many languages displaying forms like to recalculate layout every time (expensive) the collection/list/children are added/removed/updated. Batching allows the layout recalculations to be done once instead of every time the list changes.

Answer (score 0):

If the order matters, I haven't seen another way to do this.
If the order doesn't matter, You could split the StackLayout in to multiple StackLayouts and just add the individual elements inside asynchronous threads using [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-extend-the-async-walkthrough-by-using-task-whenall).

Task.WhenAll is like having multiple people do work for you at the same time, instead of just 1 person.

Comment: Task.WhenAll is executed on the background thread i think this is worth a mention

Answer (score -1):

I think Problem is in 
App.cardSetWithWordCount
It may be a linq query 
I think this goes to db every time .Just run it once and save it on variable or property

```
  var globalApp_cardSetWithWordCount = App.cardSetWithWordCount.ToList()
```

Linq is executed when  to list or toarray is called.

```
 List<int> ints = new List<int>();

        foreach(var y in query)
            ints.Add(y.Count());

        return ints.ToArray();
```

then use same take and skip format